# Chrome_InProcGp segfault at 0 error 4 in libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.7.0

Tags: qt5, yocto, qtwebengine

I am trying to build in Yocto (krogoth) with the machine haswell-wc a simple way to start up a full screen app from command line. this is simple by running the following in a bash script

~/start.sh

```
export DISPLAY=:0
X&
/usr/share/cinematicexperience-1.0/Qt5_CinematicExperience -platform xcb
```

this will launch qt5 cinematic Experience full screen with no issues.

now if i try any example that uses qtwebengine in any way on either 5.5, 5.6 or the new 5.7 i have the same error on each and the app never runs.

/var/log/messages

> Jun 26 16:02:08 haswell-wc user.info kernel: [  152.051782] Chrome_InProcGp[984]: segfault at 0 ip 00007ff4dc766d0a sp 00007ff48a7fb710 error 4 in libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.7.0[7ff4dc1af000+38c3000]

there is no issues with yocto building the distro. i have x11 and opengl in machine_features.

does anyone know how i can collect more debugging or am i missing a dependency that was not stated in yocto?